# How can change my Delphi Android App to "Dark mode"?

Tags: android, delphi, android-dark-theme

I have my app in Delphi 10.3 for Android and I'm trying to convert it to "dark mode" but many controls are missing a color attribute so some are still bright white. I have no idea how to handle the "Styles" that seem to be around.
Are there any hints you can give me on how to implement this?

Comment: "*I have no idea how to handle the "Styles" that seem to be around*" - Have you read the documentation yet? [Customizing FireMonkey Applications with Styles](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_Applications_with_Styles)

Comment: Yes, I did - but how to get my app to turn dark using this is not clear. Is there no other way to change the appearance of my app?

Comment: nvm, I found the templates.

Answer (score 0):

I put a test program in a github repository but without any explanations.
Not tested with 10.3 but should work I think.
[Light_Dark_Side](https://github.com/Serge-Girard/Light_Dark_side)
Goal was first to detect Dark/Light mode and then check how to use TStyleManager

Answer (score 0):

by putting a stylebook on my form and loading a PRESET TEMPLATE (dark in my case) I was able to change my app to dark mode without any design changes myself.